# How do I vertically and horizontally centre a div with min-height/min-width?

Tags: css

Basically I have a div that's of width 512px and height 336px. I want this div to always be positioned in the centre of the screen. If the browser window goes smaller than these dimensions, I want the scrollbars to kick in so the user can see all the content.

At the moment I've managed to position my div centrally, I've set min-width/min-height, the height is working perfectly but for some reason the min-width isn't. It seems the scrollbars are showing but the content is getting clipped on the left and I can't figure out why.

I've knocked up a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/c6Rca/) (try re-sizing the window so the content is larger than the browser window and you'll see the problem)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="vert-wrapper">
    <div id="wrapper">        
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/512/336/" width="512" height="336" />
    </div>
</div>
```

and the **CSS:**

```
#vert-wrapper { width: 512px; min-height: 336px; height: 100%; position: absolute; left: 50%; margin-left: -256px; }
#wrapper { width: 100%; min-width: 512px; height: 336px; position: absolute; top: 50%; margin-top: -158px; }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I think it's getting clipped because of your negative margin - the scrollbar only goes to the end of the content area, not into the (negative) margin.  How to fix that, though, not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the margin left. Your container is getting smaller, you try to put a margin that is too large.
Try uses media queries. I tried, and it seems to work, your picture seems to be visible in entire.I put the width of your pictures as a limit for the query and cancel all margin :

```
@media (max-width:512px){
    #vert-wrapper {left:0%; margin-left:auto; }
}
```

Comment: Ah you star, that worked perfectly. But what about browser support for older browsers?

Comment: old browers support is another question :) but i'm sure you'll quickly find lot of ressources for that (like that for exemple : http://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/)